# Sharing variables in shared library

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries, interprocess

In the book "The Linux Programming Interface" it reads:

> Although the code of a shared library is shared among multiple
> processes, its variables are not. Each process that uses the library
> has its own copies of the global and static variables that are defined
> within the library.

Is there an easier way for sharing the variables between two processes of the same library than using common IPC, like `shm_open()` and `mmap()`?

It feels overly complex sharing a class instance between two processes for a standard problem. Especially reading an already existing shared memory, how do I know e.g. the size of the class which I need to map into the  processes memory?

Comment: What would be easier than mapping common memory locations?

Comment: Using shared memory is not always the best plan. It's not especially portable, and there's a number of limitations. What's being shared here? Read-only data? Or live, read/write data?

Comment: It might also help if you elaborate on your context - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Based on the passage and what you posted in response, I'm not convinced you actually need to share instances of a variable.  I think you may be confused as to how libraries tend to work.